# Is it a good thing if my model overfits in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, overfitting

Very conceptual question:

I have a TensorFlow model that works well. I have isolated about 70 features worth of data and when training, my validation accuracy stays around 32% while my training accuracy is up to 89%! However, when I use only 24 of those 70 features, I get a validation accuracy of 38% and a training accuracy of 53%. I am using regularization, heavy dropout, and early stopping.

Is this a good problem to have? Should I keep the 70 features while boosting overfitting parameters? What should I do about this? Maybe it's a good idea to keep using only the 24 best features?

Is it generally O.K. to shed some features by just discarding them? Definitely some emotional attachment to my features here, but is it common for an ML process to simply discard these features as opposed to working with them to achieve higher accuracy?

Comment: You got a higher accuracy with fewer features. What's not to like? Overfitting is bad by definition.

Comment: True! My doubt stems from knowing that more features gives me really high training accuracy, so I'm not sure if I can work with more features to achieve higher test accuracy, or if I should just settle for the 24 features.

Comment: Maybe you can do better than 32% while retaining the other features by using more weight decay, or other form of regularization. I can not say without seeing the data. But at the end of the day, the validation set performance must decide.

Comment: If you were to see the data (maybe I could post some here?) what would you be looking for?

Comment: The optimal hyperparameters. Unfortunately I don't have the time to do it myself, but someone else might.

Comment: Oh, the model data? As in, what the hyperparameters get set to during training and such?

Comment: There is some good point in overfitting. It indicates that your model is capable to represent the dataset.Sometimes you try to overfit in order to find the proper model complexity. Now that you reached overfit, it is time to avoid it and reducing the number of features might help. Also try reducing the network size.

Comment: How large is the dataset? I would be concerned if the dataset is small (less than 1000 items say), then the overfit is more of a problem, and the advice on whether to cull your features or not would change. Also, I'd be very tempted to throw this data into something other than NNs, such as XGBoost, if only to get a benchmark accuracy.

Comment: Gotcha! Will try XGBoost. The data right now has about 2,000 items as training data, so maybe it is considered rather small.

Comment: what is the training / validation split?

Comment: 8:7, haha. How does that affect the output?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should pick the model that has the highest performance on the validation dataset.

The number of features is a hyperparameter and should be tuned during the model fitting process.

Comment: It is also possible that the data might not fit properly. I mean to say that algorithm not able to adjust parameter so we may need to see other model also.